# Record level security for multiple users in entity framework / Sql 2016

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, row-level-security

We needed to implement "who sees what" access in our application which is developed using Entity Framework 6.2.

A simple problem statement is, we have three tables -  **User**, **Department** and **UserDepartments**. In this one user can have access to multiple departments.

Can you please give us a hint or reference for this?

We came across multitenant approach in entity framework but in this case it is only one to one access ex. department table row would have user id so only one department access can be managed.

PS. Not shared any code as this is what we are looking for any reference.

Comment: You need to use a JOIN query to combine tables using ID.

Comment: Correct but this is oldest way, is there any smart way available to manage this using SQL 2016 row level security or EF multi tenant/filter approach?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Gert. Any other platform you suggest?